# PowerApps DropDown Errors

Tags: powerapps

I have a SharePoint list full of listings that users can edit/add new line items to within the app. Everything was working with my PowerApp until today and one of my users showed me the following error when trying to submit a new form:

"There was a problem saving.  Your data source may be invalid"

From here, I checked the actual PowerApp and saw a single error on the SubmitForm() function with no further explanation as to why.  I refreshed the data set (SharePoint List) associated with it, and then the errors popped up onto each dropdown item:

"The Data source Supplied to the function is invalid"

I've searched all around and have been unable to find a solution to this.  They said that this was fixed in a recent update, but I am still seeing this issue (and never saw it in the prior months).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to re-write the code that is returning the error to check what item in specific is creating the problem? Or you can create other application just to test if the same datasource returns the same error.
And how many rows have your sharepoint list? Powerapps has a limit of results he can return when using some Non-delegable functions (500 by default).

Comment: Yes, I have re-written the code, recreated the entire visual, refreshed the dataset to no avail. The data set is only about 25 rows at this point, so size shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: 1 - Try to add a row manually on your sharepoint list and check if it saves the information with no trouble  
2 - Try to create another sharepoint list with the same columns and use it in your app as a data source to see if it returns the same error. Remember that sharepoint lists have default columns with specific properties. You can rename the column but his properties will stay the same. Create your own columns to avoid this.